# SQL Server inner join conflicting columns

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

Am fixing bugs in an old classic ASP site written by another developer who has since stopped working. The following SQL command is used to call data from the database to create a table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblPropertyInfo 
INNER JOIN tblUsers on p_CustomerID = u_ID 
WHERE 
    p_Paid = 0 OR p_Enabled = 0 AND p_CustomerID <> 4 
ORDER BY " & orderby
```

The problem is that both `tblPropertyInfo` and `tblUsers` contain a column `p_Type`. In `tblPropertyInfo`, `p_Type` stores what type of property it is and this is the value we want to display in the table however I suspect this is being overwritten by the `p_Type` from the `tblUsers` table which is mostly NULL values so returns empty cells in the table.

I don't want to start playing with the table structures because they are used all over the site if I change it in one place will have find every single reference to it and update them all.

Is there a way I can specify which table to pull the column from?

Value is currently called using:

```
<%=rsProperty("p_Type")%>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to **explicitly specify** what column you want, from which tables. Doing so is a best practice anyway - don't just use `SELECT *`  in your production code! (see [Bad habits to kick - using SELECT *)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) When you do this, you can define an **alias** (a new name) for one of the `p_Type` columns

Comment: select * in this case is inherently less efficient because it is returing duplcate data on the join field. Further, pleas use () then using OR. Right now you can't tell if what was meant was  (p_Paid = 0 OR p_Enabled = 0) AND p_CustomerID <> 4 
or p_Paid = 0 OR (p_Enabled = 0 AND p_CustomerID <> 4)
so you don;t knw if the query is correct or if there is a bug there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<%=rsProperty("tblUsers.p_Type")%>
```

If that doesn't work, you could modify the query to return only one type (and any other column you may want):

```
SELECT  tblUsers.p_Type
,       ... other columns here ...
FROM tblPropertyInfo 
INNER JOIN tblUsers on p_CustomerID = u_ID 
WHERE 
    p_Paid = 0 OR p_Enabled = 0 AND p_CustomerID <> 4 
ORDER BY " & orderby
```

If you'd like to keep using `*`, you could use an alias:

```
SELECT  tblUsers.p_Type as TheType
,       *
```

Which you could reference like:

```
<%=rsProperty("TheType")%>
```

Comment: also `select tblUsers.p_Type, *`.... Since he may not know what other columns are being referenced

Comment: @EJC: Good idea.  Written like that the `*` would bring back the conflict, but an alias would fix it.

Comment: Yep, good call. Honestly I hate the idea of returning `*`, but since he probably doesn't have time to refactor for all cols referenced by this query, it's the best we can do.

Answer (score 3):

You can qualify which tabels the values you want come from:

```
SELECT tblPropertyInfo.* FROM tblPropertyInfo INNER JOIN tblUsers on p_CustomerID = u_ID WHERE p_Paid = 0 OR p_Enabled = 0 AND p_CustomerID <> 4
```

The above will select everything from tblPropertyInfo, but nothing from tblUsers

Alternatively list the properties you actually want to get back (obviously put real column names in!)

```
SELECT tblPropertyInfo.Id, tblUsers.p_Type, tblPropertyInfo.SomethingElse FROM tblPropertyInfo INNER JOIN tblUsers on p_CustomerID = u_ID WHERE p_Paid = 0 OR p_Enabled = 0 AND p_CustomerID <> 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set aliases for these columns - it is better beacause potential mistakes are eliminated.

```
SELECT *, tbl_Users.p_Type AS users_type, tbl_PropertyInfo.p_type AS property_type FROM ...
```

And of course you could access these fields using aliases.